# Assigning a classification to a shapefile to export to CAD

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, polygon, autocad

I'm trying to export a number of polygon shapefiles from Arcmap 10.3 to AutoCAD. The polygons are divided into four different classes and I need to retain the information of which polygon belongs to which class. The symbology attached to the shapefiles does not export with the polygons so is there a method of assigning a classification to a shapefile to denote the class to which it belongs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to do that, you need to add a new field in the attribute table and give it a name "Color" with type "Short Integer". Give each class a value, for example class 1 will have a color with an integer value of 1, class 2 will have a color with an integer value of 2, and so on. Then export to CAD, and you can see the polygons classified based on the color values you specified.